# How do I force a video to play over an image?

Tags: html, css, image, video, web

How do I force a video to play over an image when clicking the image thumbnail, and simultaneously scroll back to the top where the player is?

My issue and the context: I am working on a big photographic and video project and for that I decided to (try to... :) I'm not a programmer) build and launch a customized web TV entirely within a Google Blogger blog.

Everything works fine and look beautiful but I decided to fake a customized player (that is actually just a JPEG image) at the exact same place where the player is playing.

The player is working well, but it is playing underneath the image (fake player), so you will hear the sound from player but will not see the video. I would like to know how to force my player to play over this image.

Here is the link of the web TV: http://montreal-images-tv.blogspot.com/

My second issue is that when clicking the thumbnails, the site is supposed to go back to the top to see the player area, but it doesn't work very well!... :(

How can I force the site to scroll automatically to the top when clicking the thumbnails?

PS: I have already tried code like `href="#top"` with an anchor and it didn't work!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding a z-value to the video container? (higher than the image) eg. z-value for image is 1 and z-value for video is 2.

```
#video {
     z-value:2;
}

#image {
     z-value:1;
}
```

As for the scrolling, I'd try use a little jquery as it has a really nice effect.

```
       $('.clickedClass').click(
            function(){
                       $('html, body').animate({
                                 scrollTop: '0px'
                        }, 'slow');
       });
```

Any element with the class 'clickedClass', when clicked, will scroll to the top of the page.

**UPDATE: here's a jsfiddle for the scrolling: http://jsfiddle.net/CMQNT/**

Comment: Hi Jonosma, thank you very much for your precious help, now it is working great
http://montreal-images-tv.blogspot.com/

Comment: No worries :) its looking good! One tweak I'd suggest changing my example javascript from where it says 'fast' to 'slow', it will provide a much more fluid change when scrolling back to the top.

Comment: Thank you very much again for your tips, i changed fast to slow it is much better...:)